# Run some JavaScript every time a Jupyter Notebook loads

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I am running a Jupyter Notebook server and I would like to run some arbitrary javascript code to configure a notebook every time that is loaded.

Example of the code I would like to have run...

```
$('div#maintoolbar').hide();
$('div#header-container').hide();

require(["codemirror/keymap/sublime", "notebook/js/cell", "base/js/namespace"],
    function(sublime_keymap, cell, IPython) {
        cell.Cell.options_default.cm_config.keyMap = 'sublime';
        var cells = IPython.notebook.get_cells();
        for(var c=0; c< cells.length ; c++){
            cells[c].code_mirror.setOption('keyMap', 'sublime');
        }
    } 
);
```

I feel like this should be easy but can't quite find the documentation on it...

The documentation I have found often refers to IPython objects in Javascript. Any suggestions on when to use the keywords IPython vs Jupyter? For example both IPython.KeyboardManager and Jupyter.KeyboardManager are valid javascript objects in a notebook.

Comment: I found a post which suggests saving it as `.jupyter/custom/custom.js` to get it to run on startup - haven't tested it yet, though.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/AczTdZqStoM for details.

Comment: The first comment does work. Thanks. The directory needs to be made manually.

Answer (score 0):

As Hugh Bothwell already mentioned you can put you js in the custom.js file, but instead I'd suggest put it in a separate file and call in in the custom.js (there are guidelines of how to do this in the custom.js itself). You can also look up notebook extensions if you are more interested.

The difference between IPython and Jupyter is in the kernel i.e. version of ipython, if you are running environments of ipython 3.5 or higher you are on Jupyter, if you are on lower versions IPython. The bad thing is that not everything is compatible from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` may be the file to edit. I was able to add code there to disable the up & down error (something I prefer).

```
Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.remove_shortcut('up');
Jupyter.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.remove_shortcut('down')
```